# How do I create an S/MIME 4.0 certificate with X25519 with OpenSSL?

Tags: email, certificate, openssl, smime

S/MIME 4.0 as described in [RFC8551](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8551) specifies:

> 2.2.  SignatureAlgorithmIdentifier
>
> Receiving agents:
>
> - MUST support EdDSA with curve25519 using PureEdDSA mode
>
> Sending agents:
>
> - MUST support at least one of the following algorithms: ECDSA with
>   curve P-256 and SHA-256, or EdDSA with curve25519 using PureEdDSA
>   mode.
>
> 2.3.  KeyEncryptionAlgorithmIdentifier
>
> Receiving and sending agents:
>
> - MUST support ECDH ephemeral-static mode for X25519 using HKDF-256

My question:

How do I create a key and a CSR using OpenSSL to create a S/MIME certificate that will use ed25519/curve25519/EdDSA ideally with SHA-512?

Existing guides mostly show how to create a RSA key and a CSR.

Comment: Can you please provide more specifics on what exactly you have tried?  [This](https://www.dalesandro.net/create-self-signed-smime-certificates/) seems like a well documented process.

Comment: That guide is for RSA keys. But i will add some commands